# <xsl:import> in <xsl:for-each> is it possible or alternative?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

Main File :

```
<xsl:stylesheet id="myid"
 <xsl:for-each select=".">
  <xsl:import href="{concat(@attr1,@attr2)}"/>
 </xsl:for-each>
 <xsl:template name="content">
  bla bla bla
  <xsl:call-template name="templatename">
  </xsl:call-template>
 </xsl:template>
</stylesheet>
```

I need to do this kind of thing, import multiple files in a foreach from a directory & automaticaly depending on the number of existing files.

All existing file are like this one :

file1.xslt :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet id="my_awesome_id">
 <xsl:import href="default-master"/>
 <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" omit-xml-declaration="yes" media-type="text/xml" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:template name="content">
  blablabla
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template name="templatename">
  I really need help for this one :/
 </xsl:template>  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The tree is like :

Folder

|_ file1.xslt

|_ file2.xslt

|_ mainFile.sxlt

|_ file3.xslt

|_ etc ...

And I don't have any idea of the solution of this problem.

I want to achieve the dynamic importation of all xslt of the folder. Srry if it was not clear before.
I need to import all the files in the folder and without care about number of files or their names. ( I have a dynamic Xml that hold all the names & path of xslt files of the folder )

Comment: I have the feeling that you probably don't know what <xsl:import > actually means. Are you really going to use directives (templates, functions, etc) from any existing file (about which you know nothing -- even not its name) in your transformation? This seems unlikely. So, if the answer is negative, then you probably need to process all these as *data* -- not as XSLT code. In the latter case, what you need is not <xsl:import> but just the function collection()

Answer (score 2):

You need to put all `xsl:import` and `xsl:include` as children of the `xsl:stylesheet/xsl:transform` root element of your stylesheet. And you can't compute the `href` value. If you want to construct XSLT programmatically then you can of course write one XSLT that creates another XSLT as the output, but the execution of that generated XSLT is then a separate step.

Comment: I"m not sure on how to do that.
I mean , It is possible to compute automaticaly the list of files from a xml ?
I'm looking on w3C to use xsl:Transform but i don't understand how to use it in my case...

Comment: The file that is currently `mainFile.sxlt` (that file extension may have been a typeo, but something like that can be used to indicate that it is your template) can be used as a template, and use another stylesheet to generate `mainFile.xslt` with the proper `<xsl:import>` elements. Use collection() to iterate over each of the stylesheets in that directory and generate the import elements. http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-collection

Answer (score 1):

You can't do what you are trying to do - build a stylesheet at the same time as you are executing it. So what's the alternative? Difficult to know, since you don't tell us what you are trying to achieve, you only show us a non-working attempt to achieve it. But if you really need to construct a stylesheet containing all the modules that happen to be in a particular branch of your directory tree, then you can do this by means of a 2-phase process: first build the stylesheet, then run it. To build the stylesheet you can do something like this:

```
<xsl:transform....>
  <xsl:variable name="xn" select="'http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform'"/>
  <xsl:template name="main">
    <xsl:element name="stylesheet" namespace="{$xn}"/>
      <xsl:for-each select="collection('.?select=*.xslt')">
        <xsl:element name="import" namespace="{$xn}"/>
      </xsl:for-each....
```

(I've used xsl:element here to create elements in the XSLT namespace; the other way of doing it is with xsl:namespace-alias)

This relies on Saxon's implementation of the collection() function which is able to select the files within a directory. With another processor you might need to find an alternative.

Comment: In fact i as tryiing to explain that I want to acheive a dynamic importation of all my xslt files. 
I got a Xml With all path,& names of my files in the folder but i can't use it to import all Xslt of the folder.

Comment: That's not the requirement you are trying to satisfy, it's the design you have come up with in order to meet the requirement. You haven't told us anything about the requirements, only about your design, so we can't suggest alternative designs that might work better.

Comment: I agree on that point the design of this is not accurate to meet my requierement. But I can't tell you so much about that with the system i am on .